# Get Sender TextBox Name in Event Keydown

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, textbox, onkeydown

I am working on an application using WPF and C#. On a window I have number of textBoxes arranged in a grid of 5 columns and rows as many as user needs. It works like this: Initially the 1st row of 5 textBoxes is visible, the user enters appropriate values and as soon as he hits `ENTER` in the 5th textBox of the row, a new similar row of textBoxes is generated for newer entries. This keep on happening. Each textBox has a unique name using `RegisterName` method and loop.

Now my problem is that suppose I have already created 5 rows with around 25 textBoxes on window. I focus on one of the textBoxes of the 3rd row and type something that fires it appropriate KeyDown Event. In this keydown event, I need the **Name** of all the textBox that caused this event. How can I do that?

This, being done, will also help me to access all the other textBoxes of that row as I know the nomenclature using which they are named. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

Note we also set the `Name` property along with the [FrameworkContentElement.RegisterName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.frameworkcontentelement.registername.aspx) function.

```
var box = new TextBox();
var itemName = "Unique Identifier";  // Change this to your unique name per box
this.RegisterName(itemName, box);
box.Name = itemName;
box.KeyDown += (sender, args) => {
  var textBox = sender as TextBox;
  if (textBox != null)
    MessageBox.Show(textBox.Name);  // Would show "Unique Identifier"
};
```

Comment: Why do we need both `box.Name` and `RegisterName()`?

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal AFAIK It's because RegisterName() does not actually "set" the name the way you think. It Register's a given control name in a given naming context. Hence you can Register it with a different name in different contexts if required. It does make sure the given name is unique in that context or throws. Name property is simply just like defining x:Name in xaml. RegisterName() as the doc states is needed if your trying to hook Storyboards for code created controls.

Answer (score 1):

hi please use this event for the TextBox

```
TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
```

and get the id of the textboxes use sender parameter with combination with the Tag.

```
 i.e.     TextBox textbox = (TextBox)sender;
```

Comment: Not Working. `((TextBox)sender).Name` contains nothing.

Comment: Not able to get the TextBox's name in both the events.

Comment: PreviewKeyDown event is fired before the KeyDown event is fired

Comment: Please tell me how do I get the name of the sender Textbox in the event?

Comment: Kindly give names to each of the textbox if you dnt give it will not give you the name